# Web audio: Can't get ScriptProcessor node to work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, html5-audio

In web audio, I can't get the ScriptProcessor node to work in Chrome, although it works fine in Firefox.

```
// Create audio context (Chrome/Firefox)
var context;
if (window.AudioContext) {
    context = new AudioContext(); 
} else {
    context = new webkitAudioContext(); 
}

// Create oscillator and start it
oscillator = context.createOscillator();
oscillator.start(0);

// Set up a script node that sets output to white noise
var myscriptnode = context.createScriptProcessor(4096, 1, 1);
myscriptnode.onaudioprocess = function(event) {
    console.log('Processing buffer');
    var output = event.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    for (i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        output[i] = Math.random() / 10;
    }
};

// Connect oscillator to script node and script node to destination
// (should output white noise)
oscillator.connect(myscriptnode);
myscriptnode.connect(context.destination);

// NOTE: This commented-out code connects oscillator directly to
// destination, which works in Chrome as well as Firefox.
//oscillator.connect(context.destination);
```

Expected result of this sample is that it should play white noise at 1/10 volume (the oscillator is actually ignored).

You can try this code at http://jsfiddle.net/78yKV/3/ - be aware that on Firefox this URL will play white noise straight away! On Chrome 30, it doesn't give any errors, but also doesn't give any audio output. I also checked in Chrome 31 beta but saw the same results. The 'Processing buffer' log entry never appears.

To test the general audio system, if you uncomment the last line and connect the oscillator directly to the destination, it does play audio (the oscillator tone) correctly on Chrome. But I can't get the ScriptProcessor to work on Chrome.

I searched the net for tutorials etc. with ScriptProcessor but those I found either didn't come with runnable examples or didn't work (or were too complex).

(Just to make clear - this is a stripped-down sample and doesn't relate in any way to what I'm actually trying to do, so please don't tell me that I shouldn't use a ScriptProcessor to generate white noise. That's not what it's for; I do absolutely need ScriptProcessor to work for my real usage.)

I think most likely I am doing something very stupid like I have the wrong event name or something like that, but I can't find it. Can anyone help?

Comment: At first, I wasn't getting anything in Chrome 30. When I uncommented your last line *and* kept the other lines, and I got a tone plus static. Then, I re-commented the last line, and got just static (i.e., it worked perfectly).

Comment: thanks for checking it out! I can't reproduce that behaviour (i.e. if I uncomment the last line, I only get the tone, which is probably correct; if I recomment it, I get nothing)... I should have said that I'm using Chrome on Windows 7, I suspect there might be OS differences in play here.

Comment: Your code works for me in Chrome (but it didn't at first) so I think it's safe to say that your code is correctly written and there's a bug in Chrome. I suspected a race condition in your code, but you don't use any asynchronous behaviors (except the onaudioprocess, and that looks correctly set up to me).

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely possible. By the way, the thing I'm actually working on is a prototype in order to investigate whether using this on a real project is realistic, so 'nope, not yet' could well be the answer!

Comment: For information, I tested this on a Mac in Safari. For that to work I had to change a couple of function name details. On that system it kind of worked - it did at least run the event a few times (I put in a counter, looks like it ran 4 times then died without error) and make a bit of a hissing noise. So not a brilliant success there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now managed to check on several other machines and I think the problem is specific to the default audio device on my machine, which is a telephone handset using the Microsoft default USB audio driver. I've reported this to Google using the menu option in Chrome; my speculation is that the problem occurs because the handset only supports mono 16 kHz output, and somehow this causes Chrome to get confused.

I can reproduce the bug on a colleague's machine which has the same make of handset. To reiterate:

- Firefox works correctly on both machines when using the handset.
- Both machines work correctly in Chrome when you select a different output device.
- The oscillator playback works correctly in Chrome even when using the telephone handset.

Final version of test code http://jsfiddle.net/78yKV/7/

```
function doStuff(osc) {
  // Create audio context (Chrome/Firefox)
  var context;
  if (window.AudioContext) {
    context = new AudioContext(); 
  } else {
    context = new webkitAudioContext(); 
  }

  // Set up a script node that sets output to white noise
  var myscriptnode;
  if (context.createScriptProcessor) {
    myscriptnode = context.createScriptProcessor(4096, 1, 1);
  } else {
    myscriptnode = context.createJavaScriptNode(4096, 1, 1);
  }
  var buffer = 1;
  myscriptnode.onaudioprocess = function(event) {
    console.log('Processing buffer ' + (buffer++));
    var output = event.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    for (i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
      output[i] = Math.random() / 10;
    }
  };

  // Connect script node to destination
  if (osc) {
    oscillator = context.createOscillator();
    oscillator.start(0);
    oscillator.connect(context.destination);
  } else {
    myscriptnode.connect(context.destination);
  }
}
```

The white noise playback from this script (well actually a slightly earlier test version but I think it's the same) works in Chrome 30 on Windows 7, Windows 8.1, Linux, and Android 4.1; on Firefox on Windows; on an iPad (latest OS); and on a Mac using Safari 6.0.5 as well (it breaks if you open the developer tools there, but as long as you don't, it works). It only fails when using the USB telephone handset (Polycom CX300) mentioned.

So in other words, as apsillers suggested, this still looks like a Chrome bug, but a rather specific one. (By the way I also tried the latest 'Canary' version of Chrome but it didn't help.)